# MySQL stored procedure @ syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to be able to pass arguments to stored procedure, so I searched the net and encountered something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE addTmpUser 
@id varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    //some sql code
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is that I am getting a syntax error for the `@` character.

**Note:** I am using MySQL db.

Comment: added the `;` and still same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing variable types.
`@variable` is a user variable with a scope for the entire connection.
The variables in stored procedures look different, they don't have the @ before them.

Also, you need to declare them. Here is an example

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE addTmpUser(p_id varchar(10))
-- the variable is named p_id as a nameing convention. 
-- It is easy for variables to be mixed up with column names otherwise.
BEGIN
    DECLARE innerVariable int;
    insert into user (id) values (p_id);
    -- return all users
    select * from user;
END$$

DELIMITER ; 

-- and now call it
call addTmpUser(10);
```

Comment: and how should I call it? (execute the procedure)

Comment: You can do `call addTmpUser(10);`

Comment: what does this: `DECLARE innerVariable int`  line do?

Comment: That declares a variable that is only seen inside the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `IN`,`OUT`,`INOUT` to specify the parameter. So you can try this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE addTmpUser (IN id VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    //some sql code
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: now I am getting the error on the `AS` word. (unexpected `AS`)

Comment: and how should I call it? (execute the procedure)